# How can i save RatingBar value?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoPfg.png)

```
RatingBar rb;
TextView rate;
SharedPreferences wm;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puan);
    rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar))
            .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean b) {
                    final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
                    editor = wm.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("numStars", rating);
                    editor.commit();
                    int ratings = wm.getInt("numStars", 0);
                    rate.setText(rating + "/" + String.valueOf(ratings));
                }
            });
    wm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    float rating = wm.getFloat("numStars", 0f);
    rb.setRating(rating);
}
```

I have this code but when i run it i'm getting "puan has stopped" error. How can i solve this problem? Please help me thanks a lot.

Comment: You are storing a float and retrieving an int. Can we see the log?

Comment: please provide the error stack trace.

Comment: That error image tells us nothing. Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: LOGCAT

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapplication.ogrenci.example.com.puan/myapplication.ogrenci.example.com.puan.puan}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setRating(float)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `RatingBar rb` but you use method `setRating` on it. That's the problem. Add to your code

```
rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
```

and it should work. 
Also you can use later rb in `setOnRatingBarChangeListener()`.

Comment: the app was opened but when I rated it was stopped again and again

Comment: Write it just after `setContentView()`. If it doesn't work show your stack trace.

Comment: here is logcat first line;
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapplication.ogrenci.example.com.puan/myapplication.ogrenci.example.com.puan.puan}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Method `getNumStars()` return int. If you want float you should use `getRating()` method instead. Here you got more about Rating Bar in Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html